# Convert mongoDB shell command to java

Tags: java, mongodb, shell

I am trying to convert the mongodb shell code below to java. However, i run into some problems doing so. Can anyone help me with this issue?

MongoDB

```
var friend_ids = db.users.findOne(ObjectId("...")).friend_ids
db.users.find({_id:{$in:friend_ids}})
```

Java

```
ObjectId id = new ObjectId("...");                  
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("friend_ids", 1).append("_id", false);
DBObject f_ids = coll.findOne(id, fields);
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id",(new BasicDBObject("$in", f_ids)));
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);
```

The java query is as follows.

```
query={ "_id" : { "$in" : { "friend_ids" : [ { "$oid" : "..."} , { "$oid" : "..."} , { "$oid" : "..."}]}}},
```

thanks

Comment: And what exactly are the problems you are running into?

Comment: I do not get the wanted friendlist within java;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need extract friend_ids from f_ids.

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id",(new BasicDBObject("$in", f_ids.get("friend_ids"))));
```

Comment: Wow thanks,That is really quick!. i will accept as correct as soon as possible (5min)